# Password generator keeps generating the same series of passwords

Tags: excel, vba

My generator keeps generating the same series of passwords every time I run it

```
dXEFj1im
e3OpkLxq
4wKWi4SF
yBX7zb17
7kE3FLFw
yNDNNeH6
RsCjLEtP
7Zdtn1Xt
   .
   .
   .
  etc
```

Can anyone see what needs changing, I have played around I do not know enough to fix it.
Thanks

The Function

```
Function Pwd(ByVal strTemp As String) As String

Dim i As Integer, iTemp As Integer, bOK As Boolean, iLength As Integer

'48-57 = 0 To 9, 65-90 = A To Z, 97-122 = a To z
'amend For other characters If required
For i = 1 To 8
    Do
        iTemp = Int((122 - 48 + 1) * Rnd + 48)
        Select Case iTemp
        Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122: bOK = True
        Case Else: bOK = False
        End Select
    Loop Until bOK = True
    bOK = False
    strTemp = strTemp & Chr(iTemp)

' Initialize the seed using Timer.
Randomize (Timer)

Next i
Pwd = strTemp
End Function
```

The Sub

```
Sub RanPassword()
Dim rng As range
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")
    LastRow = .range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    rng.Value = Pwd(rng.Value)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not seeding the random number generator. It must be seeded every new run, to produce random results. It defaults to some number, and that number generates the same series of passwords. You must seed it by calling the `Randomize` function. `Randomize` takes one argument, the seed. A good, but not secure seed, is the system time.

Comment: theunamedguy thanks for the response, I add the seed (properly?) now I get a new pass word but I get the `same` password repeated to the last row i.e `RCAneWls` repeated n times

Comment: OK it know is working as desired, function has been updated. Thanks again!

Comment: You must change the seed every run, the same seed produces the same results.